# Problems with rescheduling Trigger in Quartz

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to create a method that reschedules my trigger. When I try to follow the tutorial from the [official quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html), I am getting errors in my reschedule() method that say

> The method getTriggerBuilder() is undefined for the type Trigger

and

> The method getKey() is undefined for the type Trigger

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;

@Component
public class OrgReportScheduler {

@Autowired 
private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

public void beginSchedule(String cronStr) throws Exception {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();

    JobDetail job = newJob(OrgReportJob.class).withIdentity("OrgReportJob", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("OrgReportTrigger", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronStr)).forJob("OrgReportJob").build();

    // schedule it
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}

public void reschedule(String cronStr) {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger("OrgReportTrigger", "group1");
    TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

    // update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
    // (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
    Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .withRepeatCount(10))
        .build();

    scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
}
}
```

Why would I be getting these errors? It seems like Eclipse isn't recognizing Quartz' APIs?

My pom.xml has these dependencies for Quartz:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What version of spring are you using? IIRC, quartz 2.2 is spring 4+

Comment: @KoosGadellaa I'm using spring boot 1.2.4. I believe you're right. I am able to build the project in terminal and successfully deploy it, however, Eclipse is showing errors in my workspace.

Comment: Have you checked the dependency view of the pom? Maybe eclipse has a different resolution and it shows conflicts?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa The dependency view looks ok.